# Expected value of division

Tags: self-learning, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be three indenependent real valued random variables. Al with finite second momennt and all with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Define
$$
    W= \frac{X+YZ}{\sqrt{1+Z^2}}
$$

> Show that $V(W\mid Z)=1$, a.e.

First we note that because on independence we have that
$$
    V(W\mid Z)=V(W)
$$
Then writing the variance in expectation form
\begin{align*}
V(W) & = E(W^2)-(EW)^2
\end{align*}
First I find $EW$. But because of lineariy of the expectation operator and the independence of the variables, we can write this as
$$
    EW= \left(EX+EYEZ\right)E\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+Z^2}}
$$
but as $EX=EY=EZ=0$ then $EW=0$.

Now lets find $E(W^2)$
$$
    E(W^2)=E\frac{X^2+Y^2Z^2+\overbrace{2XYZ}^0}{1+Z^2}=(1+1)E\frac{1}{1+Z^2}
$$

---

I am stuck here. I am not sure how to find the expectation of $1/(1+Z^2)$.

Comment: "First we note that because on independence we have that
V(W∣Z)=V(W)" Ouch! Not at all. As a first step, can you compute E(W|Z)?

Comment: Yes. I believe that I did that  above. $EW= \left(EX+EYEZ\right)E\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+Z^2}}$

Comment: Please read: compute E(W|Z), not E(W) (and the formula for E(W) in your comment is wrong in general).

Comment: I know. But $E(W\mid Z)=(E(X\mid Z)+E(Y\mid Z)E(Z\mid Z))E(1/\sqrt{1+Z^2})=(EX+EY\times Z)E(Z\mid Z))E(1/\sqrt{1+Z^2})=0$ as $EX=EY=EZ=0$. A I wrong?

Comment: You are right that E(W|Z)=0 but your computations to prove this are wrong. Actually, E(W|Z)=(E(X|Z)+ZE(Y|Z))/sqrt(1+Z^2)=(E(X)+ZE(Y))/sqrt(1+Z^2)=0. And now, E(W^2|Z)...

Answer (score 1):

First,
$$
V(W|Z)=\frac{V(X+YZ|Z)}{1+Z^2}.
$$
Second,
$$
V(X+YZ|Z)=V(X|Z)+V(YZ|Z)=V(X)+Z^2V(Y)=1+Z^2.
$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: How do you know that you can treat $\sqrt{1+Z^2}$ as a constant?

Comment: @RudFaden Why do you ask since you accepted this 1 minute after it was posted, 3 hours before your comment?

Comment: Because I would like to know.

Comment: @RudFaden Accepting an answer one does not understand is (1) strange and (2) unproductive. (Omitting `@blabla` in a comment addressed to user `blabla` makes that your comment is not signaled to them.)

Comment: @Did Have you ever seen something and thought "I understand that", but then after some time goes by, you think about again and think "hmm... there is something here I do not understand". I really appreciate you help and if I have offended you somehow, then I am sorry.

Comment: @RudFaden: The answer is already clear enough.

Comment: @gordon according to who?